# Spark SQL - select all columns while updating one

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with many columns and want to do some changes for a specific column, while keeping all the other columns untouched.

More specific I want to `explode` a column.

Currently I am specifying all the column names in the select.

```
df.select($"col1", $"col2", ..., $"colN", explode($"colX"))
```

But I would prefer not to have to specify all the column names.

I guess I could use `df.columns`, filter out the one I want to explode, and use this array in the select.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use withColumn for updating value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `filterNot`. *exp_col* is the name of the column you want to use with `explode`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode

val cols= df.columns.filterNot(_ == "exp_col").map(col(_)) :+ explode($"exp_col")

df.select(cols:_*).show
```

With `filterNot` we create a list with the items that we don't want to apply `explode` to. Then we concatenate them all together with `:+ explode($"exp_col")`.